# Customized display of composite types in Julia

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Suppose you define a new composite type in Julia and a variable of that type:

```
type MyType
  α::Int64
  β::Vector{Float64}
  γ::Float64

  MyType(α::Int64, β::Vector{Float64}, γ::Float64) = new(α, β, γ)
end
mt = MyType(5, [1.2, 4.1, 2], 0.2)
```

Now if you are in REPL mode, you can simply check the value of `mt` by typing `mt` and pressing Enter:

```
mt
MyType(5,[1.2,4.1,2.0],0.2)
```

If I want to customize the way variables of `MyType` are displayed, I can define a function and use it like `customized_display(mt)`:

```
function customized_display(me::MyType)
  println("MyType")
  println("α:$(me.α), β:$(me.β), γ:$(me.γ)")
end

customized_display(mt)
MyType
α:5, β:[1.2,4.1,2.0], γ:0.2
```

But using another function for displaying values of `mt` seems redundant. Which function do I need to extend such that by simply typing `mt`, the customized display is shown?

Comment: You can customize a `writemime` method for your type, e.g., `Base.writemime(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", mt::MyType) = println(mt.α)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define *one* of the following (they will both work and have the same effect):

```
function Base.show(io::IO, me::MyType)
    println(io, "MyType")
    println(io, "α:$(me.α), β:$(me.β), γ:$(me.γ)")
end

function Base.writemime(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", me::MyType)
    println(io, "MyType")
    println(io, "α:$(me.α), β:$(me.β), γ:$(me.γ)")
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That begs the question: What is the difference, then?

Comment: I think this is right, but corrections please: in the REPL, `display` calls `writemime`, which defaults to `showlimited` which in turn calls `show`. So both will work, but if both are defined the `writemime` one is called.

Comment: Thanks @jverzani. It's important to have that info here

Comment: This answer is outdated in 0.5 and later. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43624440/3575047) for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 8):

**Note**: The answer by spencerlyon2 is no longer correct as of Julia 0.5 and later.

Given your type

```
type MyType
    α::Int64
    β::Vector{Float64}
    γ::Float64
end
```

If you want to customize the single-line display, add a method to `Base.show` like this:

```
function Base.show(io::IO, me::MyType)
    print(io, "MyType: α:", me.α, " β:", me.β, " γ:", me.γ)
end
```

An example of single-line display being used:

```
julia> [MyType(5, [1.2, 4.1, 2], 0.2)]
1-element Array{MyType,1}:
 MyType: α:5 β:[1.2, 4.1, 2.0] γ:0.2
```

By convention, this method should **not** include any newlines. This is so that it displays nicely when embedded in other objects, like arrays or matrices. Typically, it's preferred to output something that could be parsed and evaluated into an object equal to the one being shown, but this is not a hard rule.

If you want to customize the multi-line display, add a method to `Base.show` like this:

```
function Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", me::MyType)
    println(io, "MyType")
    print(io, "α:", me.α, " β:", me.β, " γ:", me.γ)
end
```

Note that if you do not include this method, then the single-line display will be used. The multi-line display is used at the REPL when your object is shown on its own:

```
julia> MyType(5, [1.2, 4.1, 2], 0.2)
MyType
α:5 β:[1.2, 4.1, 2.0] γ:0.2
```

By convention, the multi-line display should not print any trailing new lines.