# Display default printing of composite types when it has a custom `show` defined

Tags: julia

If a package author has defined a [custom `show` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624440/371843) for their composite type, is there a way to easily print the default `show`? That is, what Julia would have shown for the composite type before the customization?

I am using Juno to step through the code of complex functions to try and I want to see the data representation but the full structure of the `struct` isn't shown due to the custom printing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Base.show_default`.

For example, [`Measurements.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPhysics/Measurements.jl) defines custom printing of the `Measurement` type:

```
julia> using Measurements

julia> x = 3 ± 0.1
3.0 ± 0.1

julia> Base.show_default(stdout, x)
Measurement{Float64}(3.0, 0.1, 0x0000000000000003, Measurements.Derivatives((3.0, 0.1, 0x0000000000000003) => 1.0))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `invoke` to make sure the default `show` method is called:

```
julia> struct Bar
       a
       b
       c
       end

julia> Base.show(io::IO, b::Bar) = print(io, "Bar")

julia> Bar(1,2,3)
Bar

julia> invoke(show, Tuple{IO, Any}, stdout, Bar(1,2,3))
Bar(1, 2, 3)
```

Also note that `dump` can be very useful in that exact scenario:

```
julia> dump(Bar(1,2,3))
Bar
  a: Int64 1
  b: Int64 2
  c: Int64 3
```

Comment: Yes, for the specific use case `dump` is the way to go.